# Prevent 'NOW()' in LINQ to EF query

Tags: mysql, linq, linq-to-entities

**UPDATE**: My original question was invalid because I was misreading the MySql logs. Sorry. Please see below, updated.

I am using the LINQ query:

```cs
var homework = ctx.Threads.Where(t => t.ClassName == "10L"
                                   && t.EndDate != null
                                   && t.StartDate <= DateTime.Now
                                   && t.EndDate > DateTime.Now)
                          .OrderByDescending(o => o.EndDate)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

This creates the SQL (MySQL 5.5.14):

```sql
SELECT
`Project1`.`id`,
`Project1`.`title`,
`Project1`.`startdate`,
`Project1`.`enddate`,
`Project1`.`class`,
`Project1`.`body`,
`Project1`.`threadtype`
FROM (SELECT
     `Extent1`.`id`,
     `Extent1`.`title`,
     `Extent1`.`startdate`,
     `Extent1`.`enddate`,
     `Extent1`.`class`,
     `Extent1`.`body`,
     `Extent1`.`threadtype`
     FROM
     `threads` AS `Extent1`
     WHERE (((`Extent1`.`class` = '10L')
         AND (`Extent1`.`enddate` IS NOT NULL))
         AND (`Extent1`.`startdate` <= (NOW())))
         AND (`Extent1`.`enddate` > (NOW())))
AS `Project1`
ORDER BY `Project1`.`enddate` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

How does LINQ to EF know to use the `NOW()` function? Surely I'm just passing it a regular `DateTime` struct by value?

If I use `var now = DateTime.Now;` and then use the `now` variable in the LINQ query, the date is passed as a literal. What's going on?

Comment: Did you try renaming `now` to, say, `now1`? This could be a simple bug.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I tried calling it `cow` and no change. Good idea though.

Comment: Hmm looks like the translation knows what `DateTime.Now` is. What about trying to fool it and saying something like `DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());`

Comment: Sorry guys, my question was wrong and I have updated.

Comment: @James After your edit the mystery is gone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ-to-whatever operates by parsing expression trees to convert from .NET code to the appropriate SQL language.  This allows the query to process as much as possible database-side instead of client-side.  As a result, when you say:

```
... myField <= DateTime.Now
```

The parser uses the expression reference `DateTime.Now`, without evaluating it, in order to convert as much as possible of the code to appropriate SQL language.  This is what allows LINQ to work efficiently, but as a side effect, *everything* in the query is interpreted as an expression and attempted to convert to appropriate SQL code.  When you store it in a variable instead, as:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
```

The value is evaluated immediately and stored into `now`, and that value is used literally in your query instead of the expression.

Comment: How does one parse an expression reference without evaluating it?

Comment: @Magnus: by using the Expression API provided in C# 3.0

Comment: Because `DateTime.Now` gets parsed into a "member access expression" with reference to the `Now` property of the `DateTime` object.  It's processed by the semantic meaning without explicitly evaluating the value.  This is how the conversion can be done entirely to SQL without any loss of meaning.

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime.Now` is a function (getter for Now property), so linq2EF when tries to make an expression tree will be see it as function. this is like to say, how `.ToString()` works in the link2EF. Also when you use it from temporary variable, it will be treated as temporary variable, like when you save the result of `.ToString()` in temporary variable, final changes doesn't effect on your output.

Answer (score 0):

Good question and answer.  I just wanted to add that in my environment, which uses Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, referencing `DateTime.Now` in a LINQ to Entities query produces the following SQL expression:

`CAST( SysDateTime() AS datetime2)`

I believe this would be similar to producing `NOW()` in MySQL, so the same behavior is seen regardless of the underlying database.

Of course this behavior can be a problem if you want the local time where your LINQ code is running as opposed to the database server.  The workaround of assigning `DateTime.Now` to a local variable and using it in the LINQ expression worked fine with MS SQL, as expected.